# How can i apply tailwind css in app folder in Next 13

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

Tailwind CSS is not applying to the app folder in the next.js v13, but it is working on the Pages and Components folder.
In the tailwind.config file, I have added

However, no CSS is being applied to components in app folder!

```
content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
],
```

Answer (score 26):

try to check the following: (works for me)

- in **next.config.js**

> set `experimental.appDir: true` to enable app directory feature

```js
const nextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    appDir: true,
  },
}
```

- in **tailwind.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  ...
}
```

- in **./app/globals.css**

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

- in **./app/layout.tsx**

> import css in layout => works fine
>
> import css in page => not working

```js
import './globals.css';
...
```

Comment: ./app/globals.css
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders Getting this error

Comment: follow the official guide (beta) [Beta-Next.js-Tailwind](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/styling/tailwind-css)

Comment: I followed this guide, but still face the same error as @AdharshM

Comment: I just created an example on the GitHub [repo](https://github.com/lorekkusu/example-nextjs13-tailwind). You can check it

Comment: I'm not saying you're incorrect, I was able to follow that guide and create a repo from scratch that can boot up.  But most projects can't just start from scratch, and currently my web monorepo built with turborepo is running into the error I listed above, despite following these instructions explicitly :)

Comment: On Next version 13.1.0 Tailwind appears to still be broken when using with the app directory. The last working version for me is 13.0.6. I was facing the same issue and this worked for me.

Comment: I have the opposite issue, it's working in page.tsx but not layout.tsx

Answer (score 8):

Had the same problem.

I moved globals.css from `/app` to `/styles`, and then import in `app/layout.tsx`.

Now works fine.

Comment: Thank you, because this fixed it for me after spending an hour trying everyone else's fix. Was about to give up trying. I have no idea why this works. It feels like something internal in NextJs 13 is misconfigured.

Comment: This should be the answer. I put _global.css_ under _app_ folder (_app/global.css_) didn't work. After created new _styles_ folder in _app_ folder (_app/styles/global.css_) and updated the import reference in _layout.tsx_ now it's working good.

Comment: This was also the fix for me. Weird.

Answer (score 7):

## Using tailwindcss with Nextjs 13 and Turbopack

##### Update dependencies

```bash
npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer concurrently
npx tailwindcss init -p
```

##### Configuring `tailwind.config.js`

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}", // Note the addition of the `app` directory.
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

##### Configuring `next.config.js`

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  swcMinify: true,
  experimental: {
    appDir: true,
  },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

##### Update `package.json`

```js
// ...
"scripts": {
    "dev": "concurrently \"next dev --turbo\" \"tailwindcss --input ./styles/input.css --output ./styles/output.css --watch\"",
    "build": "tailwindcss ./styles/input.css --output ./styles/output.css && next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
},
// ...
```

##### Create `./styles/input.css`

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

##### Create empty `./styles/output.css` file

##### Create `./app/layout.tsx`

```js
import "../styles/output.css";

export default function Root({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>{children}</body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

##### Add styles to `./app/page.tsx`

```js
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <h1 className="m-12 text-4xl text-red-600">
      Welcome to NextJS 13 with tailwindcss and turbopack
    </h1>
  );
}
```

##### Run project

```bash
npm run dev
```

##### References:

- [Tailwind CSS](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/styling/tailwind-css)
- [Use Turbopack with TailwindCSS and Nextjs 13 today](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mzBip5m-H1k)

Answer (score 5):

Ah... Figured out the issue to resolve my comment.

In my case, I had to do an additional update to my next config because I am using Turborepo.

In NextJS 12, the following was what I had in my `next.config.js`

```js
const withTM = require("next-transpile-modules")(["ui"]);

module.exports = withTM({
  reactStrictMode: true,
  experimental: { appDir: true }
});
```

However, I realized by spinning up a new turborepo from latest, that the way you transpile code has changed.  This now also needs to be declared in the experimental block.

```js
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  experimental: {
    transpilePackages: ["ui"],
    appDir: true
  }
};
```

Once you do this, along with the listed steps in the nextjs documentation, you should be able to use tailwind in Next + Turborepo :)

Answer (score 3):

I think [@lorekkusu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20363793/lorekkusu) is right, but missed something.

Assuming I'm working on /app/blog/page.tsx, *globals.css* will be required to imported again, despite it was imported at /app/layout.tsx

```
import '../globals.css' //at /app/blog/page.tsx
```

Comment: 13.0.7 had this problem, 13.0.8-canary.2 doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

If you've selected the "use /src" option while installing nextjs then you need to have your tailwind.config.js configured as such:

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
    content: [
        './src/app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
        './src/pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
        './src/components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
    ],
    theme: {
        extend: {},
    },
    plugins: [],
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this step:

Inside the root layout (app/layout.js), import the global.css stylesheet to apply the styles to every route in your application.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that all folders are intact..

meaning if you are using src

you are getting..

```
content: [
'./src/pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
'./src/components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
'./src/app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',  ]
```

So make sure that you had your components folder under app dir.(hehe)

example folder structure:
app > src, components, utils

After test and redu project to solve the issue and then following answers above nothing solves the issue, Glad I found this solution.

I hope it will help!

Answer (score 1):

Modify `postcss.config.js` and add tailwind plugin to it

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember the moment you change your folder structure to /app style in Nextjs project you need to add this line into your

in tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",   // <-------------------
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  ...
}
```

After that check following:

in next.config.js

```
const nextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    appDir: true,
  },
}
```

in globals.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

And finally, where ever you are importing the globals.css

do it like:

```
import './globals.css';
```

You can refer to this documentation [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nextjs).

Comment: This is the exact same answer: stackoverflow.com/a/74260597/6348157 posted by @lorekkusu –

Answer (score 0):

**Next config should be experimental**

```
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  experimental: {
    appDir: true,
  },
}
```

**You need to be add app directory for tailwind**

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [
    require('tailwind-scrollbar'),],
}
```

**Globals.css**

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

**Most important step**

```
import '../styles/globals.css'
```

if you are migrating to next 13 your globals.css should be in app directory after adding it. You can import it by this:

```
import './globals.css';
```

Comment: This is the exact same answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74260597/6348157 posted by @lorekkusu

Comment: No It is not the exact answer. The last line is most important step because i stuck on it. He write import './globals.css' but does not tell which directory globals.css should be in. Because in Next 12 it is outside the main project directory , located in styles folder

Comment: It doesn't matter where your CSS file is located. What matters is importing it the right way so it can be readable for all routes. So this addition is actually irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you can get rid of the existing styles in globals.css

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue with tailwind and nextjs 13 and was able to resolve it by modifying the Tailwind CSS configuration file (tailwind.config.js). In order to include all files from the 'src' folder, I added the following line to the content section of the tailwind.config.js file:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}", // This line includes all files from the 'src' folder
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to follow the four steps

1. Install Tailwind CSS

```bash
npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
npx tailwindcss init -p
```

2. Change the config to root path or prefix /src folder

```js
/* /tailwind.config.js */ 
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './src/app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
    './src/pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
    './src/components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

3. Apply the tailwind to globals css `/src/app/globals.css`

```css
/* /src/app/globals.css */
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

4. Configure PostCSS config file `/postcss.config.js`

```js
// /postcss.config.js
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
};
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case I was making the pages like
`src/pages/blog.jsx`

It did render but tailwind wasn't working.

Then after reading the [[Pages and Layout]](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/routing/pages-and-layouts) docs for the `app` directory i moved it to `src/app/blog/page.jsx`

and now it works :D