# TailwindCSS classes in NextJS 13.3.0 not working

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, next.js13

I created a new NextJS project via `npx create-next-app@latest --typescript`. There I activated ESLint, Tailwind, without `src`-folder and with `app`-folder. Then I created a file in `app/page.tsx` with the following code:

```
import React from "react";

export default function HomePage() {
  return <div className="text-red-600 text-3xl">HomePage</div>;
}
```

my `app/layout.tsx` looks like:

```
import "./globals.css";

export const metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>Test {children}</body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

and last but not least my `app/globals.css`

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

`tailwind.config.js` is:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

But if I load my page, the text is not red and not bigger. In my Browser I can see that there is a `layout.css` Tailwind Version is 3.3.1.

anybody an idea?

BR

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74259178/how-can-i-apply-tailwind-css-in-app-folder-in-next-13