# TailwindCSS utitlity classes not seen in Nextjs project

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, glob, next.js13

For some reason, when my mate tries to initialize a new Nextjs project on his PC, without adding anything extra. He just follows the prompts the Nextjs CLI gives him adding TailwindCSS and the other defaults, when he starts the dev server, it gives the warning that no utility classes are being seen. Same thing happens with the build version.

He hasn't even touched anything. He was just following the docs and running the defaults. Asked ChatGPT, and tried everything I could possibly try to help, still nothing. Meanwhile, it works seamlessly on my own PC and we're using literally the same PCs.

I don't know if it's a PC-specific issue now.

Funny enough, when he specifies an exact file to be scanned in the content property of the tailwind config file, for instance, `content: ['./app/page.tsx', './app/layout.tsx']`, it works. But when he adds the asterisks back to the pattern, it breaks again. What can we try next?

I ran the command:

`npx create-next-app@latest`

And followed the prompts and selected the defaults after which I started the dev server after all the npm packages had been installed.

- I was expecting to see the default Nextjs starter page when I visited `localhost:3000` but no styles get applied
- I see a warning in the console that says `no utility classes were detected`

I think it's a similar to this problem here: [TailwindCSS classes in NextJS 13.3.0 not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76022682/tailwindcss-classes-in-nextjs-13-3-0-not-working).